# I'm trying to write a PL/SQL Procedure that cancels a reservation. I keep getting an identifier error on a column name

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
create or replace procedure Cancel_Reservation(resid in number)
as
Begin
Update Reservation
set Res_cancel = 'yes'
where resid = reserve_id;
end;
```

Here is a picture of the table I'm working with
My goal is to cancel a reservation by inputting a reserve_id and changing res_cancel to 'yes' from 'no'. My plan is to not delete the reservation.

Here are the errors:

- Error(3,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
- Error(4,5): PL/SQL:    ORA-00904: "RES_CANCEL": invalid identifier

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoever created a table using columns with mixed case ... well, didn't think twice. In Oracle, **never** do that; causes nothing but problems. I suggest you rename the column with

```
alter table reservation rename column "Res_cancel" to res_cancel;
```

Because, as it is, you must reference that table using double quotes and exactly match letter case. So:

```
Update Reservation
set "Res_cancel" = 'yes'     --> this
```